# Delphi XE7 TFDTable View RowID error

Tags: oracle, delphi, delphi-xe7, firedac

I'm converting a Delphi 5 / BDE application to Delphi XE7 / FireDAC. One of my forms has a `TFDTable` component that points to an Oracle view containing a `group by` clause in its create statement.

This used to work fine in the BDE application, but with FireDAC I'm getting this error.

> ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT,
>   GROUP BY, etc.

I understand the error I'm getting from Oracle, but I'm not selecting `ROWID`, FireDAC is! Is there a property in the `TFDTable` that I can set to prevent it from adding `ROWID` to the query? If not, how am I supposed to use this view?

Comment: I have assigned a bonus because I'm having the same issue with fiMeta in FetchOptions.Items. Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3. The current answer is obviously not enough.

Comment: @Jan, appending of that `ROWID` column is driven by the `ReadOnly` property. Which it's not bad in this case. One just cannot identify particular tuples that might have been grouped from multiple ones. See below...

Answer (score 2):

FireDAC fetches [**ROWID**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) because it tries to identify tuples in the resultset for possible updates. For stopping that just enable the [**ReadOnly**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDUpdateOptions.ReadOnly) option which will properly make the grouped view resultset read only (properly as one cannot just identify particular tuples if they are grouped in a resultset for updating).

The SQL command is generated in **TFDPhysCommandGenerator.GenerateSelectTable** method, if you wanted to know the source of this problem. There is appended generic unique tuple identifier to the select list according to the [**ReadOnly**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDUpdateOptions.ReadOnly) property setting (which is [**ROWID**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) for Oracle DBMS).

Answer (score 0):

Include `fiMeta` in `FetchOptions.Items`.

> TFDQuery, TFDTable, TFDMemTable, and TFDCommand automatically retrieve
>   the unique identifying columns (mkPrimaryKeyFields) for the main
>   (first) table in the SELECT ... FROM ... statements, **when fiMeta is
>   included** in FetchOptions.Items. Note:
>
> mkPrimaryKeyFields querying may be time consuming;
>       the application may need to explicitly specify unique identifying columns, when FireDAC fails to determine them correctly.
>
> To explicitly specify columns, exclude fiMeta from FetchOptions.Items,
>   and use one of the following options:
>
> set UpdateOptions.KeyFields to a ';' separated list of column names;
>       include pfInKey into the corresponding TField.ProviderFlags property.
>
> When the application creates persistent fields, then initially
>   TField.ProviderFlags will be set correctly. After that, automatic
>   field setup will not happen, when the DB structure or query is
>   changed. You should manually update ProviderFlags to adjust the column
>   list. Also, if the primary key consists of several fields, then all of
>   them must be included into persistent fields. Row Identifying Columns
>
> **Alternatively, a row identifying column may be included into the
>   SELECT list. When FireDAC founds such columns, it will not retrieve
>   mkPrimaryKeyFields metadata and it will use this column.** The supported
>   DBMSs are the following:
>
> DBMS   Row identifying column
>
> Firebird   DB_KEY
>
> Informix  ROWID
>
> Interbase  DB_KEY / RDB$DB_KEY
>
> Oracle     ROWID
>
> PostgreSQL    OID. The table must be created with OIDs.
>
> SQLite     ROWID

Source : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Unique_Identifying_Fields_%28FireDAC%29

Comment: Thank you Val. I forgot to mention that I already read that article. Actually, it says to REMOVE fiMeta in FetchOptions.Items (it was selected). However, this made no difference, so I thought that I was looking in the wrong place.